How to use scrollPosition with HStack (not LazyHStack) in SwiftUI
I'm trying to implement scroll tracking using scrollTargetLayout and scrollPosition in SwiftUI. My code works as expected when I use LazyHStack, but it doesn't track the scroll position with a regular HStack.
Basically, I've noticed that my views don't always load properly when paging with the LazyHStack, but they appear fine with HStack.
Here's an example that works with HStack:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pageId: Item.ID?
    var items: [Item] = [.init(), .init(), .init(), .init()]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 1, spacing: 0)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollPosition(id: $pageId)
            
            if let pageId {
                Text(pageId.uuidString)
                    .font(.caption)
            }
        }
    }
}

However, if I try to use my own custom view it no longer works to track the scroll position:
struct CircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pageId: Item.ID?
    var items: [Item] = [.init(), .init(), .init(), .init()]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        CircleView()
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 1, spacing: 0)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollPosition(id: $pageId)
            
            if let pageId {
                Text(pageId.uuidString)
                    .font(.caption)
            }
        }
    }
}


Possible duplicate?

Their solution seemed to be switching from a regular VStack to LazyVStack. In my case, I'm hoping to use a regular stack layout. I added a link to the documentation. It seems to imply that it supports a regular stack layout, but it doesn't seem to be working.

That's not the only thing the answer suggested. You should remove the id modifier. Does that fix the issue?

The paragraph in the other answer about setting .id is relevant. I found that your example works when using an HStack if you change it to ForEach(1..<5, id: \.self) and comment out the .id modifier on the Circle.

@BenzyNeez Thanks! Removing the .id modifier seems to do the trick. Any idea why that doesn't work with HStack there?

Not really sure why it doesn't work when using a Range + .id on the child views. However, the documentation to this variant of ForEach states The instance only reads the initial value of the provided data and doesn’t need to identify views across updates, so it is hinting that ids are not tracked.

Also, I'm still having a problem. It works with just a Circle, but if I replace that with something like CircleView where the body is a Circle it no longer works.

I made some edits where I'm still not able to get it to work for my own custom views.

You omitted to include the definition of Item. I improvised by using struct Item: Identifiable { let id = UUID() } and the updated example works fine for me (Xcode 15.3, running on an iPhone 15 simulator with iOS 17.4).

Ok! I'm still testing on 15.2 so I guess a bug there.

I've dealt with this last week as well. In my case, I could use LazyHStack just fine, I just didn't want to. There are two scenarios (that I could find) where scrollPosition breaks:

id is down the hierarchy, due to some logic:
 VStack{
 Text("\(selectedElem ?? 0)").font(.largeTitle)
 ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
     HStack(spacing: 30){
         ForEach(0...100, id: \.self){ value in
                 if value % 2 == 0 {
                     Color(.green)
                         .frame(width: 10, height:100)
                 } else {
                     Color(.pink)
                         .frame(width: 10, height:100)
                 }
         }
     }
     .scrollTargetLayout()

 }
 .scrollPosition(id: $selectedElem)
 .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)

}

Using Custom Views, such as:
 VStack{
     Text("\(selectedElem ?? 0)").font(.largeTitle)
     ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
         HStack(spacing: 30){
             ForEach(0...100, id: \.self){ value in
                     SubView(id: value)
             }
         }
         .scrollTargetLayout()

     }
     .scrollPosition(id: $selectedElem)
     .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
 }



In either case, .id breaks and it does not get updated when scrolling. SwiftUI is aware of the id, because adding .onAppear modifier and setting selectedElem to 5, for example, will scroll the list at 5.
The solution I have found is to just wrap either of the cases (conditionals or custom Views) in a SwiftUI Container View (Z/H/V)Stack, like this:
VStack{
    Text("\(selectedElem ?? 0)").font(.largeTitle)
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
        HStack(spacing: 30){
            ForEach(0...100, id: \.self){ value in
                ZStack{
                    SubView(id: value)
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
    .scrollPosition(id: $selectedElem)
    .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
}


I had the exact same issue but unfortunately wrapping it in a Stack didn't work for me.
